# Compile file with system function

Tags: php

I want to compile a .c file using [PHP’s `system` function](http://php.net/system) and display the the error (if any) to another text field, else display nothing. How can I do that?

Comment: @Select0r: so, using PHP to run a system command to compile a C file. Fair enough. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could launch a compilation command with [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function:

```
$output = system("gcc -Wall -c yourtmpfile.c");
```

`outtmpfile.c` is a temporary file you need to create.

In `$output` you will have the output of the compilation command.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

"If the return_var argument is present, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable."

Then write the content of the variable to your textfield...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's [`system()`](https://www.php.net/system) function.

```
echo system('gcc file.c');
```